# especificar lenguaje en localdb

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un sistema al cual le he creado un demo, pero las fechas las manejo en el formato DMY (Dia/Mes/Año) que es el formato por defecto en español, pero cuando llevé la base de datos a local db para el demo ésta se puso en ingles (al parecer no hay forma de poner la base de datos en otro lenguaje) y el formato en ingles es MDY (Mes/Dia/Año) y esto genera excepciones.

¿Hay alguna manera de especificar en la connection string que utilice el idioma español, o de hacer que el formato para las fechas sea DMY?

Comment: Creo que SQL Server siempre entiendo yyyy-mm-dd, por ejemplo "2016-04-20"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

antes de cada consulta pones `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`.

Ejemplo:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
Select *from mi_tabla.
```

Si tenes un método que ejecute las consultas lo podes anteponer a todas las que lleguen.

```
public void EjecutarSql(string sql){
sql="SET DATEFORMAT DMY " + sql;
.
.
.

}
```

Comment: Funcionó, he estado buscando alguna solucion mas generica pero no pude, as que me he quedado con esta, gracias!